# How to prevent the screen from locking on UWP 10

Tags: win-universal-app

I want to prevent the phone to lock if the user didnt interact with the phone for some time.
In win8 phone development i used the PhoneApplicationService.UserIdleDetectionMode Property. Unfortunately i cannot find anything alike for win 10 universal app.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Simple Answer

[DisplayRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.display.displayrequest.aspx) class

```
var displayRequest = new DisplayRequest();
displayRequest.RequestActive(); //to request keep display on
displayRequest.RequestRelease(); //to release request of keep display on
```

---

### Detailed Answer

Using display requests to keep the display on consumes a lot of power. Use these guidelines for best app behavior when using display requests.

1. Use display requests only when required, that is, times when no user input is expected but the display should remain on. For example, during full screen presentations or when the user is reading an e-book.
2. Release each display request as soon as it is no longer required.
3. Release all display requests when the app is suspended. If the display is still required to remain on, the app can create a new display request when it is reactivated.

#### To Request keep display on

```
private void Activate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (g_DisplayRequest == null) 
    { 
        g_DisplayRequest = new DisplayRequest(); 
    }
    if (g_DisplayRequest != null) 
    { 
        // This call activates a display-required request. If successful,  
        // the screen is guaranteed not to turn off automatically due to user inactivity. 
        g_DisplayRequest.RequestActive(); 
        drCount += 1; 
    } 
}
```

#### To release request of keep display on

```
private void Release_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    // This call de-activates the display-required request. If successful, the screen 
    // might be turned off automatically due to a user inactivity, depending on the 
    // power policy settings of the system. The requestRelease method throws an exception  
    // if it is called before a successful requestActive call on this object. 
    if (g_DisplayRequest != null) 
    {
        g_DisplayRequest.RequestRelease(); 
        drCount -= 1; 
    }
}
```

**References** - [Prevent the screen from locking on Universal Windows Platform](http://www.developerinsider.in/2016/03/13/prevent-the-screen-from-locking-on-uwp/)

Hope it help someone!!

Comment: Please note that you wanna keep a reference to the DisplayRequest object (like in the longer snippet), otherwise if you use a local variable (like in the snippet with "var displayRequest") it won't have any effect.

Answer (score 5):

You want the [`DisplayRequest` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.display.displayrequest.aspx) in Windows 10.